# Error : mousedown is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

No matter what web page I'm on, whenever I right click on the page I get this error on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).rmousedown is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.document.onmouseup (mouseTrack.js:196)
```

What is the cause of this? Doesn't seem to cause any issues, but I'm curious where this comes from. I'm running chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)

Comment: have you tried disabling all add-ins / extensions?

Comment: This is probably caused by a chrome extension you have installed

Comment: can you show us the path for that file taken from Network tab?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney you are correct. When I disable miniGestures extension the error goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rmousedown()` may not available in JS. I think this is a type mistake, you can try with `mousedown()` instead `rmousedown()`.

Comment: Note the first sentence of the question: this is not the asker's code

Comment: You are totally right, I quote: 'No matter what web page I'm on'